# Rescaling a convex surface so that a point lies on it

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $\mathcal{S}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a **convex, bounded surface**. Now consider the rescaling operator,

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_t(\mathcal{S})=\{(tx_1,\dots, tx_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n | (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathcal{S} \}, \ \ t\in[0,\infty).
\end{equation} 
How would you set up the following proof (if the statement is true at all): let $(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then there exists a unique $t^*$ such that $(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)$ lies on the surface $\mathcal{O}_{t^*}(\mathcal{S})$.

Comment: You have to at least assert that $0$ is in $\mathcal S$, otherwise your scaling can  „tend to infinity“

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It took me a while but I now understand that $t^*$ being a unique and existing solution depends on the origin being in $\mathcal{S}$ indeed

Comment: You are welcome!